# 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion:

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to generate a list of items out of a database (sqflite). Everything seems to work fine until my database has 3 items.

When I go to the AddBodyStatsScreen and back to the BodyStatsListScreen the program crashes. When I start debugging on AVD and I have already 3 items in the database I get the following errors:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building MediaQuery(MediaQueryData(size: Size(480.0, 1042.7), devicePixelRatio: 3.0, textScaleFactor: 1.0, platformBrightness: Brightness.light, padding: EdgeInsets.zero, viewPadding: EdgeInsets.zero, viewInsets: EdgeInsets.zero, alwaysUse24HourFormat: false, accessibleNavigation: false, highContrast: false, disableAnimations: false, invertColors: false, boldText: false, navigationMode: traditional, gestureSettings: DeviceGestureSettings(touchSlop: 8.0), displayFeatures: [])):
'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 261 pos 16: 'child == null || indexOf(child) > index': is not true.

Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=2_bug.md

The relevant error-causing widget was
ListView
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#2      RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor._debugVerifyChildOrder
#3      RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor.debugChildIntegrityEnabled=.<anonymous closure>
#4      RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor.debugChildIntegrityEnabled=
#5      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.performRebuild
#6      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.update
#7      Element.updateChild
#8      ComponentElement.performRebuild
#9      Element.rebuild
#10     ProxyElement.update
#11     Element.updateChild
#12     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
#13     Element.updateChild
#14     RenderObjectElement.updateChildren
#15     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update
#16     Element.updateChild
#17     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
#18     Element.updateChild
#19     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
#20     Element.updateChild
#21     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
#22     Element.updateChild
#23     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
#24     Element.updateChild
#25     ComponentElement.performRebuild
#26     StatefulElement.performRebuild
#27     Element.rebuild
#28     StatefulElement.update
#29     Element.updateChild
#30     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
#31     Element.updateChild
#32     ComponentElement.performRebuild
#33     Element.rebuild
#34     ProxyElement.update
#35     Element.updateChild
#36     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
#37     Element.updateChild
#38     ComponentElement.performRebuild
#39     Element.rebuild
#40     ProxyElement.update
#41     Element.updateChild
#42     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
#43     Element.updateChild
#44     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
#45     Element.updateChild
#46     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update
#47     Element.updateChild
#48     ComponentElement.performRebuild
#49     Element.rebuild
#50     ProxyElement.update
#51     Element.updateChild
#52     ComponentElement.performRebuild
#53     StatefulElement.performRebuild
#54     Element.rebuild
#55     StatefulElement.update
#56     Element.updateChild
#57     ComponentElement.performRebuild
#58     StatefulElement.performRebuild
#59     Element.rebuild
#60     StatefulElement.update
#61     Element.updateChild
#62     ComponentElement.performRebuild
#63     Element.rebuild
#64     ProxyElement.update
#65     Element.updateChild
#66     ComponentElement.performRebuild
#67     Element.rebuild
#68     StatelessElement.update
#69     Element.updateChild
#70     ComponentElement.performRebuild
#71     StatefulElement.performRebuild
#72     Element.rebuild
#73     BuildOwner.buildScope
#74     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame
#75     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback
#76     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback
#77     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame
#78     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame
#79     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:145:13)
#80     PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:338:5)
#81     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:112:31)
(elided 2 frames from class _AssertionError)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
A RenderSliverPadding expected a child of type RenderSliver but received a child of type RenderErrorBox.
The relevant error-causing widget was
ListView
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4692 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was
ListView
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4692 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was
ListView
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4692 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was
ListView
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4692 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was
ListView
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4692 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was
ListView
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4692 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was
ListView
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4692 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was
ListView
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4692 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was
FutureBuilder<List<BodyStats>>
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart': Failed assertion: line 4692 pos 14: 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was
FutureBuilder<List<BodyStats>>
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Restarted application in 2.102ms.

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
'package:flutter/src/material/material.dart': Failed assertion: line 735 pos 12: 'referenceBox.attached': is not true.
The relevant error-causing widget was
Scaffold
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Here is the code:

```dart
import 'package:gym_app/database_helper.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_slidable/flutter_slidable.dart';
import 'package:gym_app/models/body_stats.dart';

class BodyStatsListScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const BodyStatsListScreen({super.key});
  @override
  _BodyStatsListScreenState createState() => _BodyStatsListScreenState();
}

class _BodyStatsListScreenState extends State<BodyStatsListScreen> {
  // void _showSnackBar(BuildContext context, String text) {
  //   ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
  //     ..hideCurrentSnackBar()
  //     ..showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(text)));
  // }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Meine Body Stats'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: FutureBuilder<List<BodyStats>>(
            future: DatabaseHelper.instance.getBodyStats('bodyStats'),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<BodyStats>> snapshot) {
              if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                return const Center(child: Text('Lade Daten...'));
              }
              return snapshot.data!.isEmpty
                  ? const Center(
                      child: Text('Keine Daten vorhanden.'),
                    )
                  : ListView(
                      children: snapshot.data!.map((item) {
                        return Slidable(
                          // Specify a key if the Slidable is dismissible.
                          key: const ValueKey(0),

                          // The end action pane is the one at the right or the bottom side.
                          endActionPane: ActionPane(
                            motion: const ScrollMotion(),
                            children: [
                              SlidableAction(
                                onPressed: (context) {
                                  Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
                                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/addBodyStats', arguments: item).then((value) => setState(() {}));
                                  });
                                },
                                backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 112, 112, 112),
                                foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                                icon: Icons.edit,
                                label: 'editieren',
                              ),
                              SlidableAction(
                                onPressed: (context) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    DatabaseHelper.instance.remove('bodyStats', item.datum!);
                                  });
                                  // _showSnackBar(context, '${item.datum} gelöscht');
                                },
                                backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFFE4A49),
                                foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                                icon: Icons.delete,
                                label: 'löschen',
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          // The child of the Slidable is what the user sees when the
                          // component is not dragged.
                          child: ListTile(title: Text(item.datum.toString())),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                    );
            }),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/addBodyStats', arguments: BodyStats(datum: '')).then((value) => setState(() {}));
          });
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And the related widget to create an item:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gym_app/models/body_stats.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:gym_app/database_helper.dart';

class AddBodyStatsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddBodyStatsScreen({super.key});

  @override
  State<AddBodyStatsScreen> createState() => _AddBodyStatsScreenState();
}

class _AddBodyStatsScreenState extends State<AddBodyStatsScreen> {
  bool taped = false;
  DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();
  Future<void> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    final DateTime? picked = await showDatePicker(context: context, initialDate: selectedDate, firstDate: DateTime(2015, 8), lastDate: DateTime.now());
    if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate) {
      setState(() {
        selectedDate = picked;
      });
    }
  }

  // void _showSnackBar(BuildContext context, String text) {
  //   ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
  //     ..hideCurrentSnackBar()
  //     ..showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(text)));
  // }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final editedBodyStats = ModalRoute.of(context)!.settings.arguments as BodyStats;

    bool inEditMode = editedBodyStats.datum != '';

    if (inEditMode && taped == false) {
      selectedDate = DateFormat('dd.MM.yyyy').parse(editedBodyStats.datum!);
    } else {}

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(inEditMode ? 'Body Stats editieren' : 'Body Stats hinzufügen'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                InkWell(
                  child: Text(DateFormat('dd.MM.yyyy').format(selectedDate)),
                  onTap: () {
                    taped = true;
                    _selectDate(context);
                  },
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              if (inEditMode) {
                await DatabaseHelper.instance.update('bodyStats', BodyStats(datum: DateFormat('dd.MM.yyyy').format(selectedDate)));
                // _showSnackBar(context, '${DateFormat('dd.MM.yyyy').format(selectedDate)} wurde editiert');
              } else {
                if (await DatabaseHelper.instance.uidExists('bodyStats', DateFormat('dd.MM.yyyy').format(selectedDate))) {
                  await DatabaseHelper.instance.update('bodyStats', BodyStats(datum: DateFormat('dd.MM.yyyy').format(selectedDate)));
                  // _showSnackBar(context, '${DateFormat('dd.MM.yyyy').format(selectedDate)} wurde editiert');
                } else {
                  await DatabaseHelper.instance.add('bodyStats', BodyStats(datum: DateFormat('dd.MM.yyyy').format(selectedDate)));
                }
              }
              Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              });
            },
            child: Text(inEditMode ? 'editieren' : 'hinzufügen'),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:gym_app/models/body_stats.dart';
// ignore: depend_on_referenced_packages
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

class DatabaseHelper {
  //SingeltonPattern
  DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();
  static final DatabaseHelper instance = DatabaseHelper._privateConstructor();

  static Database? _database;
  Future<Database> get database async => _database ??= await _initDatabase();

  Future<Database> _initDatabase() async {
    Directory documentsDirecory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirecory.path, 'gym_app.db');
    return await openDatabase(
      path,
      version: 1,
      onCreate: _onCreate,
    );
  }

  Future _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    await db.execute('''
      CREATE TABLE bodyStats(
        datum TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
        gewicht TEXT,
        koerperfett TEXT,
        muskelanteil TEXT,
        halsumfang TEXT,
        schulterumfang TEXT,
        brustumfang TEXT,
        armumfangRe TEXT,
        armumfangLi TEXT,
        oberschenkelumfangRe TEXT,
        oberschenkelumfangLi TEXT,
        bauchumfang TEXT,
        hueftumfang TEXT,
        wadenumfangRe TEXT,
        wadenumfangLi TEXT
      )
    ''');
  }

  Future<List<BodyStats>> getBodyStats(String dbTable) async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    var bodyStats = await db.query(dbTable, orderBy: 'datum');
    List<BodyStats> bodyStatsList = bodyStats.isNotEmpty ? bodyStats.map((e) => BodyStats.fromMap(e)).toList() : [];
    return bodyStatsList;
  }

  Future<int> add(String dbTable, BodyStats item) async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    return await db.insert(dbTable, item.toMap());
  }

  Future<int> remove(String dbTable, String datum) async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    return await db.delete(dbTable, where: 'datum = ?', whereArgs: [datum]);
  }

  Future<int> update(String dbTable, BodyStats item) async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    return await db.update(dbTable, item.toMap(), where: 'datum = ?', whereArgs: [item.datum]);
  }

  Future<bool> uidExists(String dbTable, String datum) async {
    var result = await _database!.rawQuery(
      'SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM $dbTable WHERE datum= "$datum")',
    );
    int exists = Sqflite.firstIntValue(result)!;
    return exists == 1;
  }
}
```

```
import 'dart:convert';

class BodyStats {
  final String? datum;
  final String? gewicht;
  final String? koerperfett;
  final String? muskelanteil;
  final String? halsumfang;
  final String? schulterumfang;
  final String? brustumfang;
  final String? armumfangRe;
  final String? armumfangLi;
  final String? oberschenkelumfangRe;
  final String? oberschenkelumfangLi;
  final String? bauchumfang;
  final String? hueftumfang;
  final String? wadenumfangRe;
  final String? wadenumfangLi;

  BodyStats(
      {this.datum,
      this.gewicht,
      this.koerperfett,
      this.muskelanteil,
      this.halsumfang,
      this.schulterumfang,
      this.brustumfang,
      this.armumfangRe,
      this.armumfangLi,
      this.oberschenkelumfangRe,
      this.oberschenkelumfangLi,
      this.bauchumfang,
      this.hueftumfang,
      this.wadenumfangRe,
      this.wadenumfangLi});

  BodyStats copyWith(
      {String? datum,
      String? gewicht,
      String? koerperfett,
      String? muskelanteil,
      String? halsumfang,
      String? schulterumfang,
      String? brustumfang,
      String? armumfangRe,
      String? armumfangLi,
      String? oberschenkelumfangRe,
      String? oberschenkelumfangLi,
      String? bauchumfang,
      String? hueftumfang,
      String? wadenumfangRe,
      String? wadenumfangLi}) {
    return BodyStats(
        datum: datum ?? this.datum,
        gewicht: gewicht ?? this.gewicht,
        koerperfett: koerperfett ?? this.koerperfett,
        muskelanteil: muskelanteil ?? this.muskelanteil,
        halsumfang: halsumfang ?? this.halsumfang,
        schulterumfang: schulterumfang ?? this.schulterumfang,
        brustumfang: brustumfang ?? this.brustumfang,
        armumfangRe: armumfangRe ?? this.armumfangRe,
        armumfangLi: armumfangLi ?? this.armumfangLi,
        oberschenkelumfangRe: oberschenkelumfangRe ?? this.oberschenkelumfangRe,
        oberschenkelumfangLi: oberschenkelumfangLi ?? this.oberschenkelumfangLi,
        bauchumfang: bauchumfang ?? this.bauchumfang,
        hueftumfang: hueftumfang ?? this.hueftumfang,
        wadenumfangRe: wadenumfangRe ?? this.wadenumfangRe,
        wadenumfangLi: wadenumfangLi ?? this.wadenumfangLi);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return <String, dynamic>{
      'datum': datum,
      'gewicht': gewicht,
      'koerperfett': koerperfett,
      'muskelanteil': muskelanteil,
      'halsumfang': halsumfang,
      'schulterumfang': schulterumfang,
      'brustumfang': brustumfang,
      'armumfangRe': armumfangRe,
      'armumfangLi': armumfangLi,
      'oberschenkelumfangRe': oberschenkelumfangRe,
      'oberschenkelumfangLi': oberschenkelumfangLi,
      'bauchumfang': bauchumfang,
      'hueftumfang': hueftumfang,
      'wadenumfangRe': wadenumfangRe,
      'wadenumfangLi': wadenumfangLi
    };
  }

  factory BodyStats.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return BodyStats(
      datum: map['datum'] != null ? map['datum'] as String : null,
      gewicht: map['gewicht'] != null ? map['gewicht'] as String : null,
      koerperfett: map['koerperfett'] != null ? map['koerperfett'] as String : null,
      muskelanteil: map['muskelanteil'] != null ? map['muskelanteil'] as String : null,
      halsumfang: map['halsumfang'] != null ? map['halsumfang'] as String : null,
      schulterumfang: map['schulterumfang'] != null ? map['schulterumfang'] as String : null,
      brustumfang: map['brustumfang'] != null ? map['brustumfang'] as String : null,
      armumfangRe: map['armumfangRe'] != null ? map['armumfangRe'] as String : null,
      armumfangLi: map['armumfangLi'] != null ? map['armumfangLi'] as String : null,
      oberschenkelumfangRe: map['oberschenkelumfangRe'] != null ? map['oberschenkelumfangRe'] as String : null,
      oberschenkelumfangLi: map['OberschenkelumfangLi'] != null ? map['oberschenkelumfangLi'] as String : null,
      bauchumfang: map['bauchumfang'] != null ? map['bauchumfang'] as String : null,
      hueftumfang: map['hueftumfang'] != null ? map['hueftumfang'] as String : null,
      wadenumfangRe: map['wadenumfangRe'] != null ? map['wadenumfangRe'] as String : null,
      wadenumfangLi: map['wadenumfangLi'] != null ? map['wadenumfangLi'] as String : null,
    );
  }

  String toJson() => json.encode(toMap());

  factory BodyStats.fromJson(String source) => BodyStats.fromMap(json.decode(source) as Map<String, dynamic>);

  @override
  String toString() =>
      'BodyStats(datum: $datum, gewicht: $gewicht, koerperfett: $koerperfett, muskelanteil: $muskelanteil, halsumfang: $halsumfang, schulterumfang: $schulterumfang, brustumfang: $brustumfang, armumfangRe: $armumfangRe, armumfangLi: $armumfangLi, oberschenkelumfangRe: $oberschenkelumfangRe, oberschenkelumfangLi: $oberschenkelumfangLi, bauchumfang: $bauchumfang, hueftumfang: $hueftumfang, wadenumfangRe: $wadenumfangRe, wadenumfangLi: $wadenumfangLi)';

  @override
  bool operator ==(covariant BodyStats other) {
    if (identical(this, other)) return true;

    return other.datum == datum &&
        other.gewicht == gewicht &&
        other.koerperfett == koerperfett &&
        other.muskelanteil == muskelanteil &&
        other.halsumfang == halsumfang &&
        other.schulterumfang == schulterumfang &&
        other.brustumfang == brustumfang &&
        other.armumfangRe == armumfangRe &&
        other.armumfangLi == armumfangLi &&
        other.oberschenkelumfangRe == oberschenkelumfangRe &&
        other.oberschenkelumfangLi == oberschenkelumfangLi &&
        other.bauchumfang == bauchumfang &&
        other.hueftumfang == hueftumfang &&
        other.wadenumfangRe == wadenumfangRe &&
        other.wadenumfangLi == wadenumfangLi;
  }

  @override
  int get hashCode =>
      datum.hashCode ^
      gewicht.hashCode ^
      koerperfett.hashCode ^
      muskelanteil.hashCode ^
      halsumfang.hashCode ^
      schulterumfang.hashCode ^
      brustumfang.hashCode ^
      armumfangRe.hashCode ^
      armumfangLi.hashCode ^
      oberschenkelumfangRe.hashCode ^
      oberschenkelumfangLi.hashCode ^
      bauchumfang.hashCode ^
      hueftumfang.hashCode ^
      wadenumfangRe.hashCode ^
      wadenumfangLi.hashCode;
}
```

I have already checked the table of the database but it looks good.